# How to create a shape that moves along the outline of a circle in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I use QT 5.11.3 and have a big problem...

I want to implement a shape that moves along the outline (or a specific path) of a circle using mouse drag.

I have referenced the example in the link below.
[How to make an item drag inside a circle in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881947/how-to-make-an-item-drag-inside-a-circle-in-qml)

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property int radius: 100

    Rectangle {
        id: circle
        width: 2 * radius
        height: 2 * radius
        radius: root.radius

        color: 'blue'
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: mark
        width: 20
        height: 20
        x: (dragObj.dragRadius <= root.radius ? dragObj.x : root.radius + ((dragObj.x - root.radius) * (root.radius / dragObj.dragRadius))) - 10
        y: (dragObj.dragRadius <= root.radius ? dragObj.y : root.radius + ((dragObj.y - root.radius) * (root.radius / dragObj.dragRadius))) - 10
        color: 'red'

        MouseArea {
            id: markArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: dragObj
            onPressed: {
                dragObj.x = mark.x + 10
                dragObj.y = mark.y + 10
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: dragObj
        readonly property real dragRadius: Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - root.radius, 2) + Math.pow(y - root.radius, 2))
        x: root.radius
        y: root.radius

        onDragRadiusChanged: console.log(dragRadius)
    }
}
```

But MouseArea has been moved not only to the outline of the circle but also to the inside of the circle.

If you have an example of moving along the contour of a shape using MouseArea or Mouse drag, please advise.

Comment: Can you share your Qml code please?

Comment: The last comment of derM to the accepted reply there should do the trick?